# QPixmap with .svg "couldn't create image from"?

Tags: qt, svg, qpixmap

i try to get an .svg to an QPixmap and i get the Error "couldn't create Image from".

Code:

```
QString test = "/home/ftp/DM262-WIF-269-0.svg";
QPixmap design(test);
ui->scan_bild->setPixmap(design);
ui->scan_bild->setScaledContents(true);
```

is there a Resolution for my Problem?

Thx
Felix

Comment: Do you get only the error message or you don't see the image too? Please clarify.

Comment: i get only the svg "overlay" without the jpg that should be there.

Answer (score 2):

The SVG loader of Qt supports only a subset of SVG. It seems that embedding of raster graphics images in SVGs is not supported. (If I remember right embedding of SVGs in other SVGs doesn't work as well. – Too sad.)

To prove that I don't tell something wrong, I tested an icon of our software.

The following image shows how the Explorer Preview plug-in (based on Qt) shows the image:

[image: SVG with embedded JPG loaded with qsvg (in Explorer plugin)]

The same image loaded into Firefox:

[image: SVG with embedded JPG loaded with Firefox]

When I import this image in GIMP, the embedded image is considered as well.

So, if you don't want to re-design your SVG icon I see only one solution: render the SVGs into raster graphics images (e.g. PNG or JPEG) which are better supported in Qt – may be, with multi-resolution icons ([`QIcon` – High DPI icons](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#high-dpi-icons)) for a better result.